# Android custom view to draw circle is expanding to whole view

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm trying to write a custom view that draws a circle, the circle keeps drawing as an oval that takes up the screen width and height

```
public class BubbleView extends ViewGroup {

private Paint borderPaint,imagePaint;
private Bitmap bmp;
private long expires;
private RectF bounds = new RectF();

public BubbleView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

void init(){
    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    borderPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

    imagePaint = new Paint();
    imagePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

void setImage(Bitmap bmp){
    this.bmp = bmp;
    invalidate();
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawArc(bounds, 0, 360, true, borderPaint);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);


}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {


}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    bounds = new RectF(0f, 0f,(float) w,(float) h);

    invalidate();
}
```

}

Something in the onsidechanged method isn'tw orking right, if i set the right and bottom bounds to an integer it works as intended.

for example

```
bounds = new RectF(0f, 0f,100f,100f);
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

First-  if you want to draw a circle, use drawCircle, not drawArc.

Secondly-  your onSizeChanged is setting the bounds rectangle to be full view size.  If you want a circle, it needs to be a square so the two radii are equal.  But better yet, use drawCircle.

Comment: 3) extend View,  not ViewGroup,  4) this.bmp is never used